# How to construct a semi-positive definite matrix in this form: (L=D-A')

Tags: graph-theory, matrices

As known, the graph Laplacian $L = D - A$ is semi-positive definite.

What if there is a matrix $A'$ where

$$ A'_{ij} = \begin{cases} A_{ij}, \quad if A_{ij} >0 \\ -\varepsilon, \quad if A_{ij} = 0 \end{cases} $$

where $\varepsilon$ is a parameter.

Is $L' = D - A'$ still semi-positive definite? Thanks.

Be more specific, Let's say the affinity matrix $A$ is :
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \end{array}

and lest $\epsilon$ = 0.1

Then $A'$ will be:
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -0.1 & -0.1 \\
-0.1 & 1 & 1 \\
-0.1 & 1 & 1 \end{array}

Answer (score 1):

If you adjust the diagonal accordingly then yes, because it would correspond to the Laplacian matrix of a slightly different edge-weighted graph.